# Simple Select Query taking long time to execute

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
select id, subject, date, source 
from TABLE_NAME 
where source = 'ABC' 
order by date desc
```

The above query fetches only 917 rows (out of 300,000 rows), but needs almost 3 minutes

[image: run time of query]

What could be the problem?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How many rows do you have your table?

Comment: about 300,000 records

Comment: For example locking by other sessions. Express edition could use 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

This may occur if your table is not properly indexed. Since you are filtering 
 917 out of 300000 records, if the column "Source" that you are searching is not indexed, then the Database Engine had to search from the Start to End to find the matching values. Try adding a Non-Clustered Index on the column - If you already have one Clustered index on any other column on the same table.

Refer the below links for more details on Indexing

[Understanding SQL Server Indexing - mssqltips.com](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1206/understanding-sql-server-indexing/)

[SQL Server Indexes Tutorial - SQL Server Planet](http://sqlserverplanet.com/indexes/sql-server-indexes-tutorial)

[Indexes in MS SQL Server - Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190263/Indexes-in-MS-SQL-Server)

Comment: but select * from TABLE_Name is also taking time of 8-9 minutes

Comment: There are so many factors that may affect the table performance. Indexing is the primary one. Check This Link for more https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/9/performance-tuning/

Comment: and since there are 300000 records, it might take some time anyway

Comment: but it never take more then 5 seconds for other tables with same amount of data

Comment: Then that might be the issue with Table Designing. Try adding some indexes and Primary key ( If not done already)